# [Error]: Please update your Heroku client to the most recent version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to run this command:

```
$heroku logs
```

I am receiving following error:

```
[Error]: Please update your Heroku client to the most recent version
```

Can someone please help me solve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Better suited for ServerFault?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply have an old version of the `heroku` gem. Just install the latest from your command line:

```
gem install heroku --version 2.3.3
```

Comment: Now latest version is 3.30.3

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to update the heroku command-line client, you can type

```
heroku update
```

at the heroku command line.

Answer (score 1):

Please uninstall your old Heroku version and install latest.

gem install heroku --version 3.30.3